# How to select all with ng-checked and ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an Ionic application(it work the same like Angularjs) and I have a little problem.

```
<ion-list class="list-inset subcategory" ng-repeat="item in shops">
      <ion-checkbox class="item item-divider item-checkbox-right" ng-model="selectAll">
        {{item}}
      </ion-checkbox>
      <ion-item ng-repeat="value in data | filter:{shopName: item}" class="item-thumbnail-left" ng-click="openProduct(value)">
...
        <div class="row">
          <ion-checkbox stop-event='click' ng-model="value.selected" ng-checked="selectAll">{{value.name}}</ion-checkbox>
        </div>
...
    </ion-list>
```

When I click on item with `ng-model="selectAll"` all items is selected. But I have property `value.selected`. It sets false for each one `value`. When I click on item with `ng-model="value.selected"` it changes. But when I want selec all and click on item with `ng-model="selectAll"` this propety doesn't change.
Help me please.

**Note:** I have ng-repeat in the ng-repeat. First ng-repeat is for shops, the second is for products. And I have a filter by shopName. And I want select all by shops. Now it works how I want, but doesn't change property `value.selected`. Value it is produt, item it is shop.

Answer (score 1):

the state of `selectAll` can be derived from the state of your other check boxes so it should not be stored as a seperate field.

You could use a getterSetter on the selectAll model to determine weather it should be checked. e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-model-options="{getterSetter: true}"/>
```

JS

```
var getAllSelected = function () {
    var selectedItems = $scope.Items.filter(function (item) {
        return item.Selected;
    });

    return selectedItems.length === $scope.Items.length;
}

var setAllSelected = function (value) {
    angular.forEach($scope.Items, function (item) {
        item.Selected = value;
    });
}

$scope.selectAll = function (value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
        return setAllSelected(value);
    } else {
        return getAllSelected();
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2jm6x4co/

Comment: Nice, didn't even know you could pass a function as a model expression.

Comment: Doesn't work good for me. I have a filter and ng-repeat in the ng-repeat. The first ng-repeat is for shops. The Secod is for products. And filter set each product to each shops by priority in the products json `shopName`. And when I click to select all it selected all products in the all shops. But I need select all by shops.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ngClick` on the item with `ng-model="selectAll"`. you can call a function in ng-click and then make selected=true for all other items where `ng-model="value.selected"`.